# Updating content types using Features

Tags: 7, features

If I have a series of existing content types in a website and I want to update those content types using a new Feature module (I added some fields), what is the correct method?

1. Add the entire node?  Will this update the existing content type?
2. Add just the new and/or modified fields?

Also, these content types were originally created by hand and not by a Feature module.  I just want to add the new fields using the Features module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest version of Features, it makes it really easy to just add the fields of the content type to the feature. Features are not meant to hold content, like entire nodes. Here's a good example of a feature I've built.

[image: Enterprise Presentation feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYC7l.png)

Comment: What version of Features are you using?

Comment: I believe that's the newest version of Features, 7.x-2.0-rc1